# Aptana Studio 3 "Building Workspace" with EXT 4 Library

Tags: aptana, extjs

I have a web project setup in Aptana Studio 3. 
I like the IDE, but so far my biggest issue with it is how long it takes for it to "Build the workspace". It seems to take forever to sort through all of the EXTJS 4.x files.

Everytime I rebuild the theme file, it takes at least 30 minutes, and the whole time the IDE can't be used. Or if I update the EXT version, it has to go through it all again.

I am sure I could remove the EXT files from the tree entirely until I put my code on the server, but I don't like for things to be scattered, and I am likely to forget to put it back.

Is there anyway I can have it exclude the EXTJS files from process it goes through?
I have try right clicking on the folder in the tree and "Exclude from Index" but that doesn't seem to work at all (This might not even be used for what I think it is).

When I put a whole new set of library files in, this process has taken up to 2 hours. And even if I stop it, it takes 5 or 6 minutes to actually stop.

I realize that the machine I am working on isn't very powerful, but I think this is a little ridiculous, especially for as often as it happens.

Any advice on this other than "get a more powerful machine" would be greatly appreciated. 
If it helps I am running Kubuntu 11.10 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Aptana but it looks eclipse based. In eclipse, you can tweak you project's 'builder' and 'validation' settings so that 'builders' don't walk through the entire ExtJS tree each time you open the workspace or save a file in the project.

There are obviously downsides to disabling validations but its a trade off. (I had the same issue but on eclipse. I moved ExtJS to a separate eclipse project and disabled all builders)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the post, Aptana's validations options don't seem quit as in depth as Eclipses are, so the screen shot above isn't quite the same. Apatana seems to only have options for Mozilla and Lint validation. Oh well, for now I am dealing with it. Hopefully a new more powerful machine in the future will fix the problems.

Answer (score 1):

just disable the javascript validator from the project properties window, this is enough.

[image: just disable the javascript validator, this is enogh]